# Real Implementation of the Shell Style Drag and Drop in .NET (WPF and WinForms)

Tags: c#

I have red the article: Shell Style Drag and Drop in .Net(WFP and WinForms), contained in the file: DragDropLib.cs Could some body, tell me, where can I find a real c# implementation of the library?

Answer (score 3):

There is a table with download links at the bottom of each article, including samples. However, the website seems broken, so I had to get the links from the HTML source. All of them link to this OneDrive directory:

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=6F4C66B0EE56CD90%21136&cid=6F4C66B0EE56CD90